# How to disable scrubbing progress bar in ExoPlayer 2 after controls reshow on touch?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm on a project that is using `ExoPlayer2`. I need to disable scrubbing in the video, with the progress bar and scrubber still visible.

However I have an issue:

1. Disable `exoProgress` view (`exoProgress.isEnabled = false`)
2. Click on Player View to hide controller UI
3. Click on Player View again to show controller UI
4. Video is able to be scrubbed again

The code looks roughly like this:

```
 <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
     android:id="@+id/player_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
     app:controller_layout_id="@layout/controls"
</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>

// controls layout file
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
    android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

binding.exoProgress.isEnabled = false
```

Does anyone know how to disable the scrubbing, even when the controls show again on touch?

When I try `playerView.controllerHideOnTouch = false` I can confirm scrubbing is disabled, so it only seems to get reverted when I reshow the controller UI.

Hiding the scrubber doesn't work.